# Array type found error when try to call from an array of string urls

Tags: java, unirest

I just have a question in running a Get request based on string urls.

The code below determines the string urls and puts each urls in an array for a table row.

```
final String URL_CORE = “/test/platform/auth”;
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
rows.forEach(row -> {
    final String clientValue = row.getCell("client");
    final String uriValue = row.getCell("uri");
    final String typeValue = row.getCell("type"));
    
    urls.add(URL_CORE + "?" + 
        (clientValue.isEmpty ? "" : CLIENT + "=" + clientValue + "&") +
        (uriValue.isEmpty    ? "" : URI    + "=" + uriValue    + "&") +
        (typeValue.isEmpty   ? "" : TYPE   + "=" + typeValue);
});
```

Within the forEach, I have this code where I just want to run the get request for the url string (for each row at a time). It is giving me an erray type expected found and wondering what am I doing wrong?

```
getRequest(queryParamsList[row]);
```

Comment: Your urls.add( is missing a closing bracket ).

Comment: Thanks, that's just a typo in the post

Comment: What is the type of rows?

Comment: @dreamcrash It's a table row like so: final List<TableRow> rows = table.getTableRows();

Comment: `clientValue.isEmpty` is invalid since `clientValue` is declared as a `String`.  I think you need to provide us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the compilation error you are asking about rather than stuff that is riddled with typos and other unrelated errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems by the name that `queryParamsList` is a List, not an array, so you have to access element by `list.get(index)` method. If you dont have the index, you can get it by `list.indexOf(element)`